# Could not execute delete route in Silex framework

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am trying to build REST for user resources using silex framework.

for the routes: **Update** and **Delete**, I am unable to execute corresponding actions.

**Update**

```
$app->put(
    '/users/{id}',
    function (Application $app, Request $request) {
        return "Updated";
    }
);
```

**Delete**

```
$app->delete(
    '/users/{id}',
    function (Application $app, Request $request) {
        return "Deleted";
    }
);
```

What is wrong with such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller functions must return a response, otherwise the framework will throw a `LogicException`:

> The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

For a "hello world" controller you can use:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse([]);
```

Comment: I have added return statements but I have not included in the question. When I submit the html forms it is giving me Routing error exception.

Comment: I have found here https://silex.readthedocs.org/en/stable/usage.html#example-get-route, it can be resolved by adding this line  "Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();"

Comment: @RavikumarJogu thank you for link. This should be the marked as proper answer.

Form started working after `Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();`